# How to get stacks which references a "stack output" parameter in a `serverless.yml`?

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

How to get stacks which references a "stack output" in a `serverless.yml`?

For example:

- *Stack A* outputs **resource A**
- *Stack B* references **resource A**

I know that if I try to exclude **resource A** from *stack A* I'll receive a message error saying *stack B* makes usage of **resource A**.

So should exists a way to list them (the referrers).

When executed:

```sh
$ serverless info --stage prod --verbose
```

Returns Stack Outputs.. but I was wondering if I could get the referrers too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/), you can put the Output section as a list item under resources:

```
resources:
  - Resources:
      ApiGatewayRestApi:
        Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi

  - ${file(resources/first-cf-resources.yml)}
  - ${file(resources/second-cf-resources.yml)}

  - Outputs:
      CognitoUserPoolId:
        Value:
          Ref: CognitoUserPool
```

Note: there is a small error in the documentation, do not forget do indent "Value" under CognitoUserPoolId.

***Update:***

This could be another option, with each part in a separate file. Make sure you begin the resources file with *Resources* and the output file with *Outputs*.

**serverless.yml**

```
...

resources:
  - ${file(resources.yml)}
  - ${file(outputs.yml)}
```

**resources.yml**

```
Resources:
  CognitoUserPool:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPool
    Properties:
      UserPoolName: my-user-pool
      AutoVerifiedAttributes:
        - phone_number
```

**outputs.yml**

```
Outputs:
  CognitoUserPoolId:
    Value:
      Ref: CognitoUserPool
```

Comment: So, my question is: How do I know who is referencing `CognitoUserPoolId`?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "who", but the CognitoUserPoolId logical resource name is specified in first-cf-resources.yml or second-cf-resources.yml. This is clearly an example and could be another resource that is specified in those templates.